# Pass the post ID

Tags: customization, javascript, login

Okay what I am trying to do is run JavaScript of the user is not logged in! I have been given the following script by the maker of "Restrict Content Pro" (The plugin I am using)

```
function pw_rcp_add_login_script() {

global $post;

if( ! rcp_is_paid_content() ) {
    return;
}

if( rcp_is_active() ) {
    return;
}

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).read(function($) {
    // Replace this with code to open login modal
    $('#id_of_modal').open();
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'pw_rcp_add_login_script' );
```

Now he has said "You will need to pass the post ID of the current page to that function."

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Aled

Comment: use [wp_localize_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass data to the script.

Comment: IF your $post is a $post object, then just use $post->ID . In your js-code you could just simple do <?php echo $post->ID;?> where you want it.